# Can I find number of methods without number of getters via CQL?

Tags: ndepend

I am using ndepend to find my code problems. And right now I found that there are too much false positives mistakes.

For example, I have a class that is not complex at all, but it does has many properties. So, I will get a warning from the NDepend that the class has too many mehods.

Here is the out-of-the-box NDepend rule to want classes with big number of methods:

```
WARN IF Count > 0 IN SELECT TYPES WHERE 
NbMethods > 20 
ORDER BY NbMethods DESC
```

Can I change the way that NDepend calculate number of methods, so I could exclude properties where I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I change the way that NDepend calculate number of methods, so I could exclude properties where I want?

Sergei, yes this is possible thanks to the following [CQLinq rule](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL):

```
warnif count > 0 
from t in Application.Types
let methods = t.Methods
   .Where(m => !m.IsPropertyGetter && !m.IsPropertySetter &&
               !m.IsConstructor)
where methods.Count() > 20
orderby methods.Count() descending
select new { t, methods }
```

Here not only you'll get the number of methods, but for each type you'll get all methods:

[image]