# NDepend query to consider the getter and setter for a property as one single method

Tags: ndepend

I have followed the link [Can I find number of methods without number of getters via CQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430086/can-i-find-number-of-methods-without-number-of-getters-via-cql) and excluded the properties from one of my NDepend queries.

One of our coding guidelines is also to ensure that the number of properties in a class(including auto-properties) should not exceed 10.(To be consistent with another guideline that no more than 20 methods can be defined for a class.)

The problem is even if we have 10 properties in a class, which is within the defined limits, the number of methods is being shown as 20. I understand that this is because a get_ and set_ for a single property are being counted as two different methods. But is there any way, by which we can change the NDepend query to have the get_ and set_ methods for a property to be counted as a single method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a CQLinq rules that warn for types having more than 10 properties and that lists the properties through a *getter* or (exclusive) a *setter*. The astute consists in using a `Lookup` table where getters and/or setters are indexed by the property name, inferred from getter/setter names:

```
// <Name>A class should not have more than 10 properties</Name>
warnif count > 0 

from t in Application.Types

let accessers = t.Methods.Where(m => m.IsPropertyGetter || m.IsPropertySetter)
where accessers.Count() > 0 // Optimization!

// Here we build a lookup that associate for each property name, the getter, the setter, or both.
// The property name is getter and/or setter simple names, without "get_" or "set_" prefixes (4 chars).
let propertiesLookup  = accessers.ToLookup(a => a.SimpleName.Substring(4, a.SimpleName.Length -4))
where propertiesLookup.Count() > 10

let properties = propertiesLookup.Select(p => p.First())
select new { t, properties  }
```

This rule also lists properties for each matched class.

[image: NDepend CQLinq Rule]

We have demand on our User Voice for [creating an NDepend.CodeModel.IProperty interface](https://ndepend.uservoice.com/forums/226344-ndepend-user-voice/suggestions/4565818-create-an-ndepend-codemodel-iproperty-interface), that will make such rule easier to develop, don't hesitate to vote for this!

Comment: Thanks, it works great. I have also voted for creation of IProperty interface.